# Answering questions with vague, non-specific but hopefully helpful, answers

Tags: discussion

I often come across questions about a piece/area of functionality with which I've had recent exposure, but find without spending a few hour researching I can't definitively answer.

However, what I can offer are links to resources and the directions in which I would start searching in order to find the answer.

Often when I've offered a non definitive answer it has been downvoted, *usually* when a definitive answer is posted afterwards.

Should questions only be answered fully and completely?

**EDIT**

See here for an example:

[Proper inputType for Credit Cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087136/proper-inputtype-for-credit-cards)

After moving Answer to the comments, seems a bit.. squashed.

Comment: If you're just "pointing to resources" stick to a helpful comment.

Comment: `After moving Answer to the comments, seems a bit.. squashed.` there are no deleted/converted answers

Comment: @genesis: Graeme did that himself and left both the comments and the answer to illustrate this question

Comment: @Mat ah, that's logic

Answer (score 5):

The rule to follow is: Don't post an answer if it doesn't answer the question.

If you have found interesting information about the topic, feel free to post these in comments. But don't post an answer with just links to resources that *might* help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comparing an answer that just reports a link to a web site that gives the answer, with an answer that explains what reported in that link, then the second is preferred.

Answers that just contain a link (or more than one link) are not considered answers because:

- Link rot happens. This means that whoever read the answer would just see a link to a page he is not able to read.
- The OP could have found the same page, but he was not able to understand what reported in that page; if the OP was able to understand the linked page, he would not have asked the question.

If you are just going to post a link, it would be better to add a comment, rather than an answer (as agf already pointed out).